# Is there a way to re-categorize content in a list form?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

There are hundreds of content pages on a site I work with. These are categorized with Taxonomy, which connects the pages to the menu system. There is a need to revise these connections. I would like to create a page (view) where these Taxonomy references couyld be updated? 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I read your question correctly, you could try the [Edittable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews) module. details from its project page:

> Editable Views lets you create Views where the fields can be edited. Fields show both the current value and a form to edit it. A 'Save' button allows saving of all the entities shown in the View.
>
> Editable fields can be added on the base entity as well as on entities brought into the View by a relationship. Other, non-editable fields may be added to the View, in which case they function normally.